# Получить значение с динамического span

Tags: javascript

Есть jQuery UI Slider, его данные заносятся в динамический span. Мне нужно получить эти данные. Я вывожу нужные данные таким методом.

HTML:

```
<span class="value">0</span>
```

JS

```
var valuePrice = document.getElementsByClassName('value')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(valuePrice);
```

В консоли мне выдает 0, но когда я двигаю ползунок, данные в console не меняются, хотя в span данные заносятся отлично.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

PS. full code

```
$(function () {

    Math.easeIn = function (val, min, max, strength) {
        val /= max;
        return (max - 1) * Math.pow(val, strength) + min;
    };

    $('#ekonom, #capital, #premium').slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 1,
        max: 500,
        slide: function (e, ui) {
            var y = Math.easeIn(ui.value, 1, 500, 2.5);
            $(this).prev().prev().text(Math.round(y));
        }

    });
    function squareMeter() {
        var valuePrice = document.getElementsByClassName('value')[0].innerHTML;
        var result = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
        var ekonomPrice = 1390;
        var capitalPrice = 2200;
        var premiumPrice = 4170;
        result = valuePrice.toString() + ekonomPrice;
        console.log(valuePrice);
    }

});
```

Comment: А вы выполняете эту функцию при скроле?

Comment: Функция на слайдер скролл отдельно

Comment: Чтобы Вам могли помочь попробуйте привести минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: и когда вызывается squareMeter???

Comment: squareMeter() у меня вызывается после этой функции.

Comment: когда двигается ползунок вызывается обработчик события  `slide:` Вот там и вызывайте `squareMeter()`

Comment: 1 раз? а кто будет ее вызывать при изменении слайдера? Встаньте в нее отладчиком и посмотрите, что происходит

Comment: Спасибо всем большое. Вставила в slide, и все заработало)